# powershell script for getting extended file property list and signer details inside a directory/path

Tags: powershell, csv

I want the signer info of a file along with extended properties for the entire directory arranged columnwise in csv format and using the following powershell script to achieve it:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE" -Recurse |Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionInfo | select-object FileDescription, OriginalFilename, FileVersion | Get-AuthenticodeSignature "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE" | Export-Csv C:\Users\abc\Documents\c.csv
```

I get a 0 bytes *CSV* file on running this script, don't understand if I'm wrong/right because the script doesn't give error on execution

Comment: So, you're piping `FileDescription, OriginalFilename, FileVersion` to `Get-AuthenticodeSignature`?

Comment: I cant understand if im doing it right.Is it the way I should be doing it?

Comment: You are doing it wrong.

Comment: How do I combine two commandlets in a single script then?

Comment: Think on yourself: `gci` pipes a list of files to `select`, which expands `VersionInfo` and pipes further to your 2nd select. This selects the three properties and pipes it to get-auth.code.sig. But does Get-AuthentocideSignature accept those values as `$InputObject`? You might want to pipe gcms output to get-auth.code.sig and pipe its output to your csv.

Comment: _How do I combine two commandlets in a single script then?_ [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-5.1) e.g. Do you mean single script or single line? You know, that you can seperate multiple commands with a new line or semicolon?